# Two save buttons on rails form with slightly different functionality

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a form of some length, for which I've set up an ajax save button so that a user can save their progress and continue editing the form.  This works very well; no complaints.

**My problem** is that I would like a second button a the end of the form for when the user is done with editing and wants to make a final submission.  The key difference in functionality would be that it redirects to a "Form submitted, thank you for blah blah blah" page after saving.

**I've tried** using a standard submit button (`<%= f.button :submit, "Submit", id:"incorporation_submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>`), but this seems to not work; nothing is submitted nor do I find anything in the logs upon clicking it.  (I'm guessing it's because I've defined remote to be true for the form).

My form is outlined below; I've removed the form fields and sidebar contents to minimize clutter.  The final submit button is the `f.button :submit` as it appears above.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="active main-content">
  <%= simple_form_for @incorporation, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div>
      .
      .
      .
     Form contents
      .
      .
      .
    </div>
      <!-- Sidebar -->
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul id="sidebar_menu" class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#">Menu<span id="main_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a></li>
        .
        .
        .
        Sidebar navigation tools
        .
        .
        .
      </ul>
      <%= button_to "Save Progress", incorporation_path(@incorporation), remote: true, id:"save" %>
    </div>
    <div>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", id:"incorporation_submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Update 1:**
If I remove the `:remote=> true` from my `simple_form_for`, the submit button works just fine, redirect and all (obviously the ajax save button does not though)

**Update 2:**
I've found that if I remove the `button_to` from the sidebar, I get an output from my logs; however I am unable to successfully redirect the browser to a little static page that I set in my controller.  See output below:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/welcome/index
Completed 302 Found in 134ms (ActiveRecord: 11.2ms)


Started GET "/welcome/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-10 01:39:21 -0700
Processing by WelcomeController#index as JS
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
  User Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 1747ms (Views: 1740.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
```

Comment: What does "does not seem to work" means? Please clarify your error or problem.

Comment: @dgilperez Thanks for the response; fair question.  What I mean is that nothing is submitted nor do I find anything in the logs upon clicking it.  (I've included this explanation above for future readers)

Comment: Are you sure nothing is submitted, ie did you check the logs? Any errors in the browser console? The ``remote: true`` would need a ``.erb.js`` file in the server to respond to the petition, maybe that is missing. Otherwise I don't see anything strange in the last ``f.button :submit``.

Comment: Another thing to try: comment out the ``button_to`` and try to submit then.

Comment: @dgilperez It does actually produces something in the logs when I remove the `button_to`.  However I can't get it to actually redirect (see output above).  As you suspect, I don't have any `.erb.js` should it be in my view?  This hasn't prevented me from saving using ajax however so maybe I don't know where to look.

Comment: Have a look at this part of the Ruby Guides to understand how you should build the thing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like both buttons should call the update action in your controller. From there, you can then check the param 'commit' and handle your response as you wish. For example,

buttons in view:

```
<%= form.submit 'Save' %>
<%= form.submit 'Update' %>
```

check which button was clicked in controller:

```
if params[:commit] == 'Save'
  ... redirect somewhere ...
else
  ... do something else ...
end
```